# Turn clustering code from python to flask

Tags: python, flask, graph, cluster-analysis, k-means

Does anyone know how to turn this python code into a code that I can run with flask?

```
km4=KMeans(n_clusters=3,init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)
y_means = km4.fit_predict(reduced_data)
predict=km4.predict(reduced_data)
data= np.array(reduced_data)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
plt.scatter(data[y_means==0,0],data[y_means==0,1],s=50, c='blue',label='Cluster0')
plt.scatter(data[y_means==1,0],data[y_means==1,1],s=50, c='orange',label='Cluster1')
plt.scatter(data[y_means==2,0],data[y_means==2,1],s=50, c='green',label='Cluster2')
plt.scatter(km4.cluster_centers_[:,0], km4.cluster_centers_[:,1],s=100,marker='s', c='black', alpha=0.7, label='Centroids')
plt.xlabel('Profit')
plt.ylabel('income')
plt.legend()  
plt.show()
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start with a boilerplate flask app. Check a flask tutorial for that. Like: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world
Then check what the output is, you can only output HTML in Flask. So your graphics should be converted to a JPEG to be able to display them in a web browser.